# Webpack Bundle file has no CSS style and UI component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I created my project(Project 1) using CRA. The project 1 is using some Ui library like "Reactstrap" and customized CSS sheet. it is fine by its own. Then I bundle the main component file using webpack and trying to export it to other project(Project 2).

The webpack looks like this for my project:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        /*Client Side*/
        entry: './src/App.js',
        output:{
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: "2FA.js",
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: '2FA'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html",
                filename:"./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename:"[id].css"
            })
        ]
    } 
]
```

The targeted entry, `App.js` is the main UI that has everything in it:

```
export default class TwoFA extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          /* All the staff */
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Bundling project 1 produces 3 files in `dist` folder: `2FA.js`(the main js file), `index.html` and `main.css`

Then at Project 2, i imported the bundle file by downloading Project 1 from git and use the component like so:

```
import TwoFA from 'my-app/dist/2FA'

ReactDOM.render(<TwoFA />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The javascript rendered fine. However, it has zero css in it. No UI library or no customized css sheet. This whole component just became plaint javascrip without any CSS.

I inspected the page. The divs still have classNames, but these classNames do nothing.

I am trying to figure out why and how to fix it, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the bundled library by the name given in `output.library` in your WebPack configuration, namely `2FA`.

Comment: what do you mean? I did specify output.library as 2FA

Comment: @aDev could you put this in [a snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that I can troubleshoot this with my assumption?

Comment: do you want me to include webpack.config as well or just the main component from Project 1

Comment: We need the webpack config there as well as that seems to be the source of the problem

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/m75kp6wq0p. First time using sandbox, forgive me if I miss something. please let me know if you need any other code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Сheck your connection main.css file in you main index.html file.

So how you do MiniCssExtractPlugin they must be connected separately.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
```

Comment: If i run the bundle in webpack-dev-server. It is fine. However, it is problematic when I export it and use it in other project.

Comment: In the problem clearly says webpack. What do you mean when you say other project?

Comment: I am trying to bundle one of my project with webpack and import it to other project. When I tried to render bundled project, the UI is gone. However, if I run webpack-dev-server on bundled project itself, the UI renders fine.